# How to instal gluon plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, javafx, gluon

I am having a hard time trying to instal the gluon plugin for eclipse..

I am using  [this](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gluon-plugin) link but i cant get it to work... This is the error:

Unable to read repository at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gluon-plugin.
Unable to read repository at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gluon-plugin.
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gluon-plugin is not a valid repository location.

Edit: Also the instal button isn't working

Any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Eclipse Marketplace by opening eclipse and go to "help" in the toolbar at the top and click "Eclipse Marketplace" a window will popup, scroll down and click "Browse for more solutions". A new window will open and you can search for gluon and install it.

Here is a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFLmmFPQYFo

Comment: good video but my eclipse does not have market place @ILikeThings

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: i have e(fx)clipse 4.5 and 4.6

Comment: What happens is that when i instal from "Instal new software", it stucks on "Calculating requirement and dependencies" and after that... "Cannot perform operation"